# Nginx / Django: Accessing static files results in 403 Forbidden

Tags: django, nginx

I've been trying to debug this for several hours and I'm not sure what else to check. My problem is that Nginx doesn't server Django static files. Accessing static files results in the error **403 Forbidden**.

The exact error from **nginx error log** is:

`2013/02/11 05:42:13 [error] 22526#0: *29 open() "/home/mydomain/public_html/test2/src/bootstrap.css" failed (13: Permission denied), client: XXX.XXX.XX.XX, server: mydomain.com, request: "GET /src/bootstrap.css HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mydomain.com"`

Here is my **nginx config file**:

```
server {
    listen   XX.XX.X.XXX:80;
    server_name mydomain.com;
    root /home/mydomain/public_html/test2/app;
    # serve directly - analogous for static/staticfiles
    location /media/ {
        # if asset versioning is used
        if ($query_string) {
            expires max;
        }
    }
    location /admin/media/ {
        # this changes depending on your python version
        root /home/mydomain/public_html/test2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib;
    } 
    location /src/ { 
        autoindex    on;   
        root /home/mydomain/public_html/test2;
    }     
    location / {
        proxy_pass_header Server;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off; 
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_connect_timeout 10;
        proxy_read_timeout 10;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
    }
    # what to serve if upstream is not available or crashes
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /media/50x.html;
}
```

Static files are stored in `/home/mydomain/public_html/test2/src`.

I've tried `chown mydomain.mydomain -R *` and `chmod 755 /home/mydomain -R *` without any effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a **working solution** to my initial problem:

```
server {
    listen   XX.XX.X.XXX:80;
    server_name mydomain.com;
    root /home/mydomain/public_html/test2/app;

    location /admin/media/ {
        # this changes depending on your python version
        root /home/mydomain/public_html/test2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib;
    }
    location /src {
        root /home/mydomain/public_html/test2;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_pass_header Server;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_connect_timeout 10;
        proxy_read_timeout 10;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
    } 
    # what to serve if upstream is not available or crashes
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /media/50x.html;
}
```

Comment: Hi could you explain what the exactly happens with those configuration??

Answer (score 2):

use this

btw. [IfIsEvil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com;

    #access_log /var/log/nginx/x_access.log;
    #error_log /var/log/nginx/x_error.log;

    location /static {
        alias /path/to/your/static;
    }

    location /media {
        alias /path/to/your/media;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass_header Server;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off; 
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_connect_timeout 10;
        proxy_read_timeout 10;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you pointed me to the right direction. I slightly customized your answer. I'll post it as a separate answer for others to see what were the changes compared to my original file. Thanks again!

Comment: I have this directive, but continue getting a 403 error.
    location ^~ /static {
        alias /home/username/public_html/aaa/front/xxx/xxx/static;
    }

and if i remove the ^~ i got a "500 server error"

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to use try_files. The advantage of this is that Nginx will first look for a real file to serve, and if it fails to find one it passes execution to your django app. This is perfect for serving a dynamic sitemap.xml for example since you do not need to special-case the file in nginx.conf.

```
# Set default expires headers (used for static assets)
expires 30d;

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name mydomain.com;

  root /some/path/assets/;
  try_files $uri @django;

  location @django {
    expires -1d;
    proxy_set_header  Host $host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_redirect    off;
    proxy_pass        http://unix:/some/path/server.sock;
  }

  location /static/admin/ {
    alias /some/path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/;
  }
}
```